# How to setup multiple separated oracle database dockers on same Host?

Tags: oracle, docker

I want to setup and run multiple oracle database docker containers on the same host (Red Hat OS), each database will use a separated area on the host to store data. These docker containers use the same [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/oracledb19c/oracle.19.3.0-ee).
For example:

- Container 1 will listen on port 1521 and store data in /home/user/oracle_data/container_1 folder on host.
- Container 2 will listen on port 1522 and store data in /home/user/oracle_data/container_2 folder on host.
- Container 3 will listen on port 1523 and store data in /home/user/oracle_data/container_3 folder on host.

Can you tell me the best practice to solve this task?

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: What is the reason for this architecture? Strictly speaking from an Oracle database perspective, this is not an ideal configuration. Use Oracle's Container DB/Pluggable DB on a single Docker image rather than multiple Docker images, if possible. Multiple Docker images would unnecessarily duplicate many processes and use significantly more server resources, and as you noted require more open network ports. With a CDB/PDB architecture you get better resource consolidation and a generally improved security posture; this is Oracle's recommended architecture.

Comment: Only use multiple Docker images if you need to support multiple Oracle versions, similar to having multiple Oracle Home directories.

Comment: Firstly, as @pmdba pointed out, I have many oracle DB versions need to be tested. Secondly, there are many testers in my team and each tester want to execute on a separated database to avoid collision each other.

Comment: I'm not sure that using Docker really gains you anything in your case. You still - apparently - want to centralize the DB management, have persistent data, etc. Even with multiple DB versions, why introduce the added complexity of Docker to the architecture? Allow each developer to have their own PDB to avoid interference and keep resource consumption as low as possible. Docker makes more sense if you're going to be constantly spinning up new/fresh DBs for testing, or if you want your developers to host multiple DBs on their personal workstations or local VM hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside every container keep using the default port of 1521.
Remap this port to external world to your custom port.

Same thing with folders - keep the folders the same inside the container, remap them to different folders in the host

For example, if using docker-compose, for the first container use:

```
ports:
   1521:1521
volumes:
   /oracle/data1:/oracle/data
```

for the second container use:

```
ports:
   1522:1521
volumes:
   /oracle/data2:/oracle/data
```